# AWS amplify deployment issue

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I am junior Dev and have been using heroku to deploy my applications but recently decided to jump to aws.
i have encountered an error "Cannot read property 'accessKeyId' of undefined" when i try to amplify init -y my front-end fullstack app.
Any advice will be awesome. Thank ya.

I was Expecting the app would initialize AWS emplify

Comment: do you have your `accessKeyId` set up as an environment variable?

Comment: @TerchilaMarian i believe i did when i was installing aws in the command line, i ran amplify configure and it took me through some steps and i recall putting accesskey and secret accesskey was one of them, unless i need to do something more.

Comment: i have also tried this "export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=***********
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=*******
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1".  But still get the error when I init -y

Comment: have you reloaded your bash profile after you added the exports?

Comment: i have just tried, i ran exec bash and then exit, was that right? i really appreciate your time @TerchilaMarian

Comment: you can `source ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc` or close and reload the terminal. the values should be available via `echo $accessKeyId`